# Trying solve ActionView::MissingTemplate in production (heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, actionmailer

I have a headache when trying to implement sending email by gmail at production (heroku). When running `heroku logs` I get the following:

```
2016-04-15T18:20:47.117490+00:00 app[web.1]: ClienteMailer#boas_vindas: processed outbound mail in 5.8ms
2016-04-15T18:20:47.118282+00:00 app[web.1]:    (0.7ms)  ROLLBACK
2016-04-15T18:20:47.117474+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-04-15T18:20:47.118705+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 31ms (ActiveRecord: 6.5ms)
2016-04-15T18:20:47.120623+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template layouts/mailer with {:locale=>[:"pt-BR"], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
2016-04-15T18:20:47.120613+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-04-15T18:20:47.120624+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/app/views"
2016-04-15T18:20:47.120625+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/mailers/cliente_mailer.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in boas_vindas'
2016-04-15T18:20:47.120625+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2016-04-15T18:20:47.120627+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/cadastro.rb:6:in `envia_email_boasvindas'
2016-04-15T18:20:47.120626+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/mailers/cliente_mailer.rb:5:in `boas_vindas'
2016-04-15T18:20:47.120626+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/mailers/cliente_mailer.rb:6:in `block in boas_vindas'
2016-04-15T18:20:47.120627+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/cadastros_controller.rb:18:in `create'
```

It seems to be a problem with the template, but the mailer template is in the directory `layouts/mailer.html.erb`.

Below is the code ActionMailer:

## mailers/application_mailer.rb

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
      default from: "Example <example@gmail.com>"
      layout 'mailer'
    end
```

## mailers/cliente_mailer.rb

```
class ClienteMailer < ApplicationMailer
    def boas_vindas cliente
        @cliente = cliente
        mail(:to => @cliente.email, :subject => 'Example.') do |format|
            format.html { render 'boas_vindas' }
        end
    end 
end
```

## models/cadastro.rb

```
.
.
.
after_create :envia_email_boasvindas
def envia_email_boasvindas
    ClienteMailer.boas_vindas(self).deliver
end
.
.
.
```

In development everything works normally. What am I missing or forgetting?

Comment: Within `mailer.html.erb`:
`<body>
       <%= yield %>
</body>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the problem, but you don't need to specify the format in the mailer. Just do it:

```
class ClienteMailer < ApplicationMailer
    def boas_vindas cliente
        @cliente = cliente
        mail(:to => @cliente.email, :subject => 'Example.')
    end 
end
```

This is the only difference from what I usually do I can see.

Comment: I made the changes, unfortunately, I keep getting the same error log in heroku.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by removing `layouts 'mailer'` of `application_controller.rb`. It seems that it does not use `mailer.html.erb` layouts but `boas_vindas.html.erb` of `cliente_mailer.rb`. Strange that this only happens in production, will be setting of enviroments?